# Selling partner Aws Sign4 wrong calcualation for vendor

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using the API method "Directly making calls to Selling partner APIs".

I followed all the steps correctly:

1. Request a Login with Amazon access token - This API is working successfully & Getting access token.
2. Construct a Selling Partner API URI - After that, I took access_token and pass into options header request- 'x-amz-access-token'.
3. Add headers to the URI
4. Create and sign your request

After calling API `https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/vendor/orders/v1/purchaseOrders`
 I am getting a signature response with error- 
 `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.`

My code:-

```
let options = {
    service: 'execute-api',
    region:'eu-west-1',
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/vendor/orders/v1/purchaseOrders/?includeDetails=true&createdBefore=2020-04-20T14:00:00-08:00&createdAfter=2020-04-14T00:00:00-08:00',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'host':'sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com',
      'x-amz-access-token':access_token,
      'x-amz-date': '20200604T061745Z',
      'user-agent':'My App(Language=Node.js;Platform=Windows/10)'
    }
  }

let signedRequest = aws4.sign(options,
{
  secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
})

console.dir("signedRequest");
console.dir(signedRequest);

delete signedRequest.headers['Host']
delete signedRequest.headers['Content-Length']

request(awsres, function(err, res, body) {
    console.dir("err");
    console.dir(err);
    console.dir("res");
    console.dir(res.body);
});
```

Comment: Can You please share more details on it. From the initial investigation looks like you haven't provided the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.

Comment: @Dipak did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the signature is calculated the same way it is calculated in other AWS services.

- [Signature Version 4 signing process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) docs.
- [@aws-sdk/signature-v4-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/signature-v4-node) -- official AWS SDK v3 signature package, but v3 is very much in beta. But I imagine they have figured out the signature package, as it wouldn't be possible to interact with the API without it.
- [aws-signature-v4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-signature-v4) NodeJS package